# Ошибка SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, babel

Проект построен на базе шаблона https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

После устанвоки библотеки https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete получил в консоли ошибку:

```
vm.js:88 Uncaught E:\tempgen\node_modules\vue-google-autocomplete\src\VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <template>
                                                                                                                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:263:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:10)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1038:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл `webpack.renderer.config.js` нужно добавить в массив `whiteListedModules`  название библиотеки `'vue-google-autocomplete'`

```
`let whiteListedModules = ['vue','axios','vue-electron', 'vue-router', 'vuex', 'vuex-    electron','element-ui', 'vue-google-autocomplete']`
```